# View filtering on SharePoint 2013 = dynamically build query string

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Another day, another strange request from end users :)

My problem is simple = they want a search page, with multiple combobox/dropdownlist/managed metadata picker and a single search button.
Advanced search page ? No, because users want to see search results directly in documents library view and not search results page :(

At first glance, i'm thinking about tweaking a search results page to look like a document view library. Unfortunately, i know that losing the ribbon can be a huge problem on the future.

Once upon a time, with SharePoint 2010, I was able to dynamically build query string for filter a view. I'm looking for a reference or finely documented blog post about it for SharePoint 2013

Comment: Do you want to deploy the list view using feature/module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying the list definition then in `Schema.xml` file you have to create a new view declaratively.

Below is the sample xml for view:

```
  <View BaseViewID="13" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Incident" DefaultView="FALSE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="FilteredActions.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>         
    </ViewFields>
    <Query> // here the query to filter the data falls.
      <Where>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Incident" LookupId="TRUE" />
            <Value Type="Lookup">{IncidentId}</Value>
          </Eq>
      </Where>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="IncidentId" Location="QueryString(IncidentId)" DefaultValue="0"/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
```

You can copy the any existing view's schema (for example: AllItems). Add new Parameter in `<ParameterBinding>`. Define the name of the Query String parameter you are going to pass. In `<Query>` tag you can filter the records using CAML query. To get the value of query string parameter in `{<QPName}`.

Hope this helps to solve your query.!!

Comment: I'm trying to use FilterValue and FilterField query string directly on URL. It seems to be OK with managed metadata !